# Getting an Uncaught TypeError: when i try to use my .tableExport in a button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm facing a huge problem since this morning, i'm trying to export my table into a pdf file. The script works fine if i put it in a  without nothing else, the page load and the dl starts.

But i want it in a button ! And when i put it like this :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#downloadPDF').on('click', function (e) {
        console.log("test");
        e.preventDefault();
        $('table').tableExport({ 
            type: 'pdf', 
            jspdf: {     
                orientation: 'l', 
                format: 'a3', 
                margins: { 
                    left: 10, 
                    right: 10, 
                    top: 20, 
                    bottom: 20 
                }, 
                autotable: { 
                    styles: { 
                        fillColor: 'inherit', 
                        textColor: 'inherit' 
                    },
                    tableWidth: 'auto' 
                } 
            } 
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<button type="button" id="downloadPDF" class="btn btn-default">Default</button>
```

I get this error in the chrome console :

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tableExport is not a function(anonymous function) @ Auto:290jQuery.event.dispatch @ jquery-1.10.2.js:5109elemData.handle @ jquery-1.10.2.js:4780

I can't understand why. Because it works well when it's not in an event.

Comment: What is ` $('table')` ?

Comment: this is the id of my table

Comment: Then it should be `$('#table')`

Comment: Alright, it worked with just 'table' when i put it without a button, anyway i added it, and still not working :/

Comment: Do you have any jquery plugin to execute the function `tableExport` on a dom element ?

Comment: Well i think i missunderstood your question, what do you mean ?

Comment: You're trying to execute a function which is not native in jquery

Comment: Ok and how can it work on pageload ? And more important how can i make it work when the button is pressed ? Because, i'm including exportTable in my header.

Answer (score 0):

To do it, you need [a table export plugin](https://github.com/kayalshri/tableExport.jquery.plugin).

Add these imports in your page :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="tableExport.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.base64.js">

//and these if you want export to pdf
<script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf/libs/sprintf.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf/jspdf.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf/libs/base64.js">
```

Obviously, replace src paths by where you downloaded it.